# Persist text validation error message?

Tags: validation, error-messages, viewstate, page-validation

Is it possible to persist a validation error message on a lightning component?
For example, if you get a validation message of some kind on child A in an accordion, then collapse it and open child B, then collapse child B and reopen A, the validation error message will no longer be present.

Could you just create an event to fire that causes that state to get saved, or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Using the messages that are tied to the components in the component library - probably not, as you've just described. However, if you make the validation error a part of the parent component (assuming you're building a custom component here) you can do a lot more with it, maybe lock the accordion if there's an error state or something like that. Can you share what components you're using? Knowing the components and whether they're Aura v. LWC can help us answer you.

Comment: Thanks @nbrown this is a modal with a tab set, and tab set I want to do this in contains a vertical list of lightning-cards

Comment: It sounds like you want to disable tab switching so long as there is an error state? If so, you will need to write your own logic that disables tabs (if possible).

Comment: In my case, what I want - in Tab 1, child card A has some error on an input field. User navs to card B in tab 1 and expands it, then goes back to child A. Would want the child A card to still have the validation error message. Guessing this wont be simple

Comment: From the sound of it, the error state might get reset when tabs are switched. You can either see if you can force the state to re-evaluate on tab change, or track the errors at a higher level so that the parent component knows tab A, child A has errors, for example.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips, really appreciate it